# How to get total matched records according to match query from elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 1.4.5 with couchbase. I want to retrieve all the records according to my match query. The "total" gives me the total matched records number but i am getting only 10 records at a time. My query is

```
$searchParam['index']="events";
$searchParam['type']="couchbaseDocument";
$searchParam['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['createdUnder']=$id;
$searchParam['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]['match']['status']="active";
$searchResults=$client->search($searchParam);
```

Comment: using the size param ex:`$searchParam['body']['size']="20"` should allow you to  fetch the required results but ideal you should use [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_search_operations.html#_scan_scroll) api to fetch all the matched.

Comment: thanks @keety , its really works for me what i exactly want..

Comment: sure np glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
$searchParam['body']['size']="20"
```